# Setting Collection using getResourceModel function issue

Tags: collection, model, xml

This is the content of the Grid.php file
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Banner_Grid extends

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{ 
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('mymodule/banner_collection');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
}
```

this is the content of the Mynamespace/Mymodule/Model/Mysql4/Banner/Collection.php

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Mysql4_Banner_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {  
        echo 11111; exit();
        $this->_init('mynamespace_mymodule/tablename'); 
    }  
}
```

**The table from db is called mynamespace_mymodule_tablename**
This is the content from the config.xml in which I guess smth is wrong

```
<global>
    <models>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mynamespace_mymodule_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
            <mynamespace_mymodule_mysql4>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <mynamespace_mymodule_tablename>
                        <table>mynamespace_mymodule_tablename</table>
                    </mynamespace_mymodule_tablename>
                </entities>
            </mynamespace_mymodule_mysql4>
        </models>
</global>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have the namespace_modulename in your entity definition in config.xml file, try with this code instead :

```
<global>
    <models>
            <mynamespace_mymodule>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>mynamespace_mymodule_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </mynamespace_mymodule>
            <mynamespace_mymodule_mysql4>
                <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <tablename>
                        <table>mynamespace_mymodule_tablename</table>
                    </tablename>
                </entities>
            </mynamespace_mymodule_mysql4>
        </models>
</global>
```

Also, when calling from Grid file, call to your model collection needs to modified as

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{ 
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('mynamespace_mymodule/banner_collection');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
}
```

as defined in your config.xml file.

Comment: It is the same, to get the big picture what I want to achieve is this article: https://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified. I followed each step. BUt I get blocked  with the collection

Comment: I added one more thing, take a look.

Comment: ok now its getting to Mynamespace_myModule_Model_Mysql4_Banner_Collection, in the constructor, but I got this error message: 
dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Comment: Although, that asks for a separate question, have you actually used that code ? You need to have either Banner or Tablename entity, both can not go along.